# How do I edit my program in order to assign a variable to an array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, refactoring

so I am currently working on a project for school. My initial program ran fine and then I was told to refactor my array into an array list.

Eclipse is highlighting one specific line with the error that

`'The lefthand side of an assignment must be a variable'`.

Everything else in the program seems to have no other issues.

I have tried a few different things to fix this problem and have hit a wall. I've attached a copy of the section of code causing me issue, and I hope this question isn't too vague.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class StockPrices {

    static final int MAX_STOCK_COUNT = 24;
    static final int MIN_STOCK_PRICE = 10;
    static final int MAX_STOCK_PRICE = 100;

    // Create the array of Stock Objects
    ArrayList<Stock> myStocks = new ArrayList<Stock>();

    public StockPrices() {
        char startChar = 'A';
        String tmpSymbol = null;
        int startPrice = 0;
        int priceRightNow = 0;

        for (int idx = 0; idx < MAX_STOCK_COUNT; ++idx) {
            // Generate stock symbol for testing
            tmpSymbol = "" + (char) (startChar + idx) + (char) (startChar + idx + 1) + (char) (startChar + idx + 2);
            // Generate random data for pricing
            startPrice = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(MIN_STOCK_PRICE, MAX_STOCK_PRICE + 1);
            priceRightNow = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(MIN_STOCK_PRICE, MAX_STOCK_PRICE + 1);
            myStocks.get(idx) = new ArrayList <Stock>(tmpSymbol, startPrice, priceRightNow); //The issue is with this line starting with "myStocks"**
            System.out.println(myStocks.get(idx));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> myStocks.get(idx) = new ArrayList (tmpSymbol, startPrice,
>   priceRightNow);

This line of code is getting an item from your ArrayList. Not setting.

Furthermore, even if it was *setting* instead of getting, you are assigning an item in your ArrayList to be another ArrayList... but your ArrayList<> is not an ArrayList of ArrayLists (follow me)? It is an ArrayList< Stock > (list of Stocks).

If you want to add a new stock, or update, you need to do:

```
myStocks.add(new Stock(tmpSymbol, startPrice, priceRightNow); // add new

// OR

myStocks.set(idx, new Stock(tmpSymbol, startPrice, priceRightNow); // update at index
```

Answer (score 0):

myStocks.get(idx) returns object at `idx` index in `MyStocks` array list.

Refer this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-

That is, basically it returns instance reference of object at index `idx` in myStocks array list.

Now for statement

`myStocks.get(idx) = new ArrayList <Stock>(tmpSymbol, startPrice, priceRightNow);`

you are assigning reference value with object reference returned by `new ArrayList <Stock>(tmpSymbol, startPrice, priceRightNow);`, which doesn't make sense.

`=` can be used when variables are on left hand side of the expression.

Since, `myStocks.get(idx)` returns reference of object at index `idx` (not the actual object), which is not a variable to store the reference of `new ArrayList<Stock>(tmpSymbol, startPrice, priceRightNow)`.

Now, for your code to work, since you are overwriting the reference of arraylist at index `idx`. using `set()` will solve the problem.

Refer this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-

something like this

`myStocks.set(idx,new Stock(tmpSymbol, startPrice, priceRightNow));`

Thanks.